# Obtaining tags associated with a role using BOTO3

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, boto3, roles, amazon-iam

Is there a way to obtain the tags associated with a particular role? The following does not produce the tags for the role:

```
import boto3

iam=boto3.client('iam')
response = iam.get_role(RoleName='xxxxx')
print(response)
```

Also, IAM does not appear to be supported within the [resource groups tagging api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)

Answer (score 0):

Any IAM role can be identified by it's arn (amazon resource name).
IAM role does not have tags.

Comment: IAM Roles do have tags: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/add-tags-to-manage-your-aws-iam-users-and-roles/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this function, it will return a dict with all Role tags:

```
list_role_tags(**kwargs)
Lists the tags that are attached to the specified role. The returned list of tags is sorted by tag key. For more information about tagging, see Tagging IAM Identities in the IAM User Guide .

See also: AWS API Documentation

Request Syntax

response = client.list_role_tags(
    RoleName='string',
    Marker='string',
    MaxItems=123
)
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_role_tags